# I am trying to auto submit a form on ASP page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a change to do on an ASP page.  The page currently has a login form (username and password fields) but now that login is handled by Azure B2C sign in so I am parsing the JWT with some javascript to extract just the email address and then want to pass that through to the code behind method to perform the login to the web application.  I am parsing the email address OK and populate the username form field with that, I then have a `form.submit()` in the JavaScript to submit the form and call the code behind method which handles the login. However, my form isn't being submitted. How can I do this better? I think it's a bit messy as it is and I'd rather have something to just do the login and get rid of the login form completely.

Login ASP page code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="LoginForm_Module" CodeFile="LoginForm.ascx.cs" %>
<!-- «Start| Login Form» -->
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnLogin">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function parseJwt() {
            var URIString = window.location.href;
            const myArray = URIString.split("=");
            var token = myArray[2];
            var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
            var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
            var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(window.atob(base64).split('').map(function (c) {
                return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
            }).join(''));

            const obj = JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
        
            document.getElementById('Main_ctl01_txtEmail').value = obj.emails[1];

            var form = document.getElementById("login_form");
            form.submit();

            return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
        }
    </script>
 
    <body onload="javascript:parseJwt()">
        <div class="form" id="login_form">
            <span class="form-body">
                <div class="item">
                    <span class="item-body">
                    <div class="input">
                        <asp:TextBox id="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass='textbox' Text="" MaxLength="100"/>          
                    </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <span class="item-body">
                    <div class="input">
                        <asp:TextBox id="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" AutoComplete="off" CssClass='textbox' Visible="false" MaxLength="100"/>
                    </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </span>
            <div class="buttons">
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogin" ValidationGroup="User" Text="Login" OnClick="btnLogin_Click"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</asp:Panel>
<!-- «End| Login Form» -->
```

Code Behind Method:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var user = User.FindByEmail(txtEmail.Text);
    
    if  (user.IsLocked)
    {
        // Display the notification on the page:
        Controls.Add("<div class='account-locked-message'><span class='bold'>Your account has been locked.</span> Please contact PA Consulting on the following email to access your account again: <span class='bold'><a href='mailto:{0}'>{0}</a></span></div>".FormatWith(Settings.Current.ContactFormRecipientEmail));

        return;
    }

    /*
    if (user != null && user.IsLocked)
    {
        // Display the notification on the page:
        Controls.Add("<div class='account-locked-message'><span class='bold'>Your account has been locked.</span> Please contact PA Consulting on the following email to access your account again: <span class='bold'><a href='mailto:{0}'>{0}</a></span></div>".FormatWith(Settings.Current.ContactFormRecipientEmail));
        return;
    }
    
    if (user != null && user.Password != txtPassword.Text)
    {
        user.IncrementLoginRetryCount();
    }
    
    if ((user == null || user.Password != txtPassword.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username and/or password. Please try again.");
        return;
    }
    
    if (ShouldShowRecaptcha && !(new Recaptcha().Validate(Request)))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error in your Recaptcha response. Please try again.");
        return;
    }
    */

    ImpersonationContext.Abort();
    
    user.ResetLoginRetryCount();
    user.AuditTrail(AuditableAction.LogIn);
    user.LogOn();
    
    Response.Redirect(PageUrl("Login > Dispatch"));
}
```

I am expecting the form to be submitted by the Javascript function but it is not working and remains on the login page

Comment: You do not have a form. You have a div. Change `<div class="form" id="login_form">` to `<form class="form" id="login_form">`

Comment: Also when it works, the `return JSON.parse(jsonPayload);` will likely not execute since the page will be reloaded immediately

Comment: Lastly remove `onload="javascript:parseJwt()"` from the body tag and add `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',parseJwt)` inside the script tag

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I have made the changes you suggested, but the form is still not submitting?

Comment: Anything in the console?

Comment: Also why not use the submit event instead of the click event?

Comment: In the console, I see this error:  Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSubscriber%2fHome.aspx:119  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'submit')
    at parseJwt (Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSubscriber%2fHome.aspx:119:50)

Comment: Do you mean change OnClick="btnLogin_Click" = to onSubmit ?

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not have a form. You have a div. Change

   `<div class="form" id="login_form">`
   to
   `<form class="form" id="login_form">`
2. remove `onload="javascript:parseJwt()"` from the body tag and add
   `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',parseJwt)`
   to the script.
3. Check you have a form in the view-source of the page and that it has an ID of "login_form" and nothing else in the page has an ID of "login_form" and also that the asp button is a submit button when it renders
4. You have some script `protected void btnLogin_Click` and you execute something on click of the button. Try to find out how to just submit a form instead of having the validation in codebehind. You can change the validation to be client side and have normal input validation on the server

Something like

```html
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="LoginForm_Module" CodeFile="LoginForm.ascx.cs" %>
  <!-- «Start| Login Form» -->
  <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnLogin">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function parseJwt() {
        var URIString = window.location.href;
        const myArray = URIString.split("=");
        var token = myArray[2];
        var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
        var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
        var jsonPayload = decodeURIComponent(window.atob(base64).split('').map(function(c) {
          return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }).join(''));

        const obj = JSON.parse(jsonPayload);
        document.getElementById('Main_ctl01_txtEmail').value = obj.emails[1];
      }
      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        parseJwt()
        var form = document.getElementById("login_form");
        form.submit(); // will not work if there is anything called name or id=submit in the form
      });
      
    </script>

    <body>

      <form class="form" id="login_form">
        <span class="form-body">
         <div class="item">
            <span class="item-body">
               <div class="input">
                  
                  <asp:TextBox id="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass='textbox' Text="" MaxLength="100"/>          
               </div>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <span class="item-body">
               <div class="input">
                  <asp:TextBox id="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password" AutoComplete="off" CssClass='textbox' Visible="false" MaxLength="100"/>
               </div>
            </span>
        </div>
        </span>
        <div class="buttons">
          <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnLogin" ValidationGroup="User" Text="Login" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </body>
  </asp:Panel>
  <!-- «End| Login Form» -->`
```